# Issues With adding style programmatic ally to Vertical navigation menu using Razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nopcommerce

I am trying to decorate the vertical navigation menu using razor in one of my projects , i am trying to add style depending on the functionality with no success , the issue is i have subcategories and categories all in one table , thats why i have to call all the categories , subcategories within a one ul and then decorate them on hover , active , inactive etc. Below is the code, any ideas why the bold statement doesnt works.

```
  <div class="listbox">
        <ul class="">
            @foreach (var category in Model)
            {
                <li class="@(category.IsActive ? "active" : "inactive")" 
               @if (category.NumberOfParentCategories > 0)

                {

                  <text>style="background-image: url('/Content/images/cat-ul-li-list.png');border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-left: 15px;color:#5F9E95;min-height:27px;"</text>

                   }
                   **@if (category.NumberOfParentCategories > 0 && category.IsActive == true) 


                    {

                    <text>style="background-image: url('/Content/images/cat-ul-li-active.png') !Important;"</text>**
                    }><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { categoryId = category.Id, SeName = category.SeName })">@category.Name

                </a>
                 </li><li class="separator"></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.block-category-navigation .listbox ul .inactive
{
background-image: url('images/cat-rt-arrow.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left center;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-color: #5F9E95;
border-bottom-style: solid;
padding-left:15px;
min-height:27px;
padding-top:8px;
}

.block-category-navigation .listbox ul li a:hover { color: #404041; }
 .block-category-navigation .listbox ul{ background-image: url('images/cat-ul-active.png') !Important; padding-left:15px;min-height:27px; padding-top: 8px;}
```

The demonstartion can be seen on test website :[Quadratech](http://www.teamlemon.co.uk/c/1/haemostasis)

Any suggestion or assistance will be appreciated, if this can be done using other methods like css and jquery. I have attached the image of what i am exactly looking for where Haemostasis is the category selected below is the subcategories for haem.. with the subcategory resistance active, and right down the bottom are the other inactive categories.
 :[image]

Answer (score 1):

You add two `style` attributes to your tag.

I would combine them into one.

And cleanup the generation for the LI tag a bit. By first doing the test, and storing the result in some variables:

```
    const string STYLEBASE= "border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-left: 15px;color:#5F9E95;min-height:27px;";

       var style = "";
       var backgroundimage = "";
       if (category.NumberOfParentCategories > 0) {
          backgroundimage = "background-image: url('/Content/images/cat-ul-li-list.png');";
          style = STYLEBASE;
       }

       if (category.NumberOfParentCategories > 0 && category.IsActive == true) {
          // override the background image
          backgroundimage = "background-image: url('/Content/images/cat-ul-li-active.png');
       }

       <li class="@(category.IsActive ? "active" : "inactive")" style="@Html.Raw(style + " " + backgroundimage)" >
```

Comment: I tried your code with no success , I cant get the required results like image above

Comment: @MrA, Maybe you should be a little more specific.

Comment: I mean , the navigation menu is not working as the image says , when the sub-category is clicked the parent-category background image dissapears